# Where does NVME driver register its namespace as block device in Kernel code?

Tags: kernel, driver, nvme

I am trying to figure out where does NVME driver register its namespace as block device in latest kernel code (5.x.x).

The last explicit block device registration for NVME is seen at kernel 4.3.x [block/nvme-core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.3.6/source/drivers/block/nvme-core.c) where `register_blkdev` and `unregister_blkdev` were called.

From kernel 4.4.x `block/nvme-core.c` was removed and seems everything about `nvme` is moved into `drivers/nvme`. However I am not able to see any explicit block device registration at [drivers/nvme/core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7-rc7/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c) although there are many places using the `blk-mq` APIs.

Does anyone have some idea where and why was the change?